# How to set the DS and ES register equal to CS?

Tags: x86, cpu-registers, fasm

my problem is the following: I have a program that has its data and code together in the same segment (Code Segment). I want to use the ESI and EDI registers to compare a few strings, but they are in the Code Segement.

The ESI and EDI registers are offsets of the DS and ES register segment, (DS:ESI), (ES:DI), but I want to change the address where the Data Segment and ES segment point, and set it equal to the Code Segment Address.

Please, help me. Thanks for your answers. Can give me a short example about how to do it??

Answer (score 4):

Easy way:

```
  PUSH CS
  PUSH CS
  POP  DS
  POP  ES
```

Naturally, executing

```
  PUSH DS
  PUSH ES
```

before you play with DS and ES, and

```
  POP  ES
  POP  DS
```

when you're done and want to restore your segment settings is an easy way to resolve that local problem.

Comment: I have tried with that solution, but my program crashes. I will look it again to see if I am making another error. Thanks for your help, @Magoo

Comment: @jhonny6721 depending on the OS you are running under it may be the case that CS (and its copies in other selectors) is read-only and any data operation trying to modify the data will throw hardware fault. See http://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention (turned on on Windows machines by default)

Comment: You know those two pops to restore `ds` and `es` are the wrong way around, right?

Comment: @harold - wondered how long it'd take someone to spot that... Well, actually...recovering from a bout with the dread 'flu...

Comment: Thanks for all. @harold Somebody (I don't remember who) said that I can't change the DS and ES segments because they are under the control of the Windows OS. If you try to change them, you can do a big error. Somebody knows how to change the DS and ES without crash the code???

Comment: @jhonny6721 if you're on windows, this entire problem doesn't exist. CS, DS and ES all have offsets of zero anyway, so you can pretend they don't exist. (GS and FS have nonzero offsets though)